# Overriding an array element and the structure and mechanism of stack

Tags: c, arrays, stack

I have read about stacks. The stacks accepts one operation at the time. The program either pops or pushes an item from or into the stack.

Now, arrays are also an interface to an underlying stack. Is that true?

If yes, then how could it be possible that with an array of 50 element, we do the following:

```
$x[30] = "A new value to be written on the older value of this index.";
```

Notably I mean C language (and since PHP's source is in C, I brough a PHP example.)

I mean how the operation on the stack is the handled? Because only the last element of an stack could be edited at the time, then how such statement (above example) is handled?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: when you assign an array like that to a string it is just a matter of a pointer being set to a memory position where the string starts - there is no stack involved.

Comment: The stack is a lifo implementation in hardware.  (and source code can access any stack address.   An array has no intrinsic implementation, it just exists.  what happens with an array depends only on the source code that incorporated that array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In memory, when you call a new function, a new stack frame is started. And when you go out of scope `}`, a frame is popped out of the memory so it is called stack.

About memory access, you can access any writable offset of the memory to write.

So accessing an array using `a[10]` is like accessing `stack_pointer + offsetOf_A + 10 * sizeOf_A[0]`

> Now, arrays are also an interface to an underlying stack. Is that
>   true?

No, this is not. It is stack of frames and not of (composite or non-composite) variables. Memory can still be accessed using offsets.

Answer (score 1):

`Now, arrays are also an interface to an underlying stack. Is that true?`

No. You can use an array to implement a stack, but you wouldn't normally use a stack to implement an array.

Comment: Ow...I got it. I totally misunderstood the concept. Though, now I got the point and accessibility.